# Run subscription only once

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, google-cloud-firestore

I need to run `userProfiles$.subscribe(async res => {` only once. But it works infinitely. Can you tell me how to avoid it?

This is the [**video of that issue**](https://youtu.be/nllTmLZ6yjw):

*.ts*

```
async loginWithGoogle(): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const result = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
      const userId: string = result.additionalUserInfo.profile.id;
      const userProfile: AngularFirestoreDocument<UserProfile> = this.fireStore.doc(`userProfile/${userId}`);
      const userProfiles: AngularFirestoreCollection<UserProfile> = this.fireStore.collection('userProfile/', ref => ref.where('email', '==', result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email));
      const userProfiles$: Observable<UserProfile[]> = userProfiles.valueChanges();

      userProfiles$.subscribe(async res => { //problem is here
        if (res.length == 0) {
          await userProfile.set({
            id: userId,
            email: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email,
            creationTime: moment().format(),
            lastSignInTime: moment().format()
          });
        } else {
          await userProfile.update({
            lastSignInTime: moment().format()
          });
        }
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

I have tried to convert it to `promise` like below. But no difference. Maybe I did it wrong?

```
 userProfiles$.map(async res => {
        if (res.length == 0) {
          await userProfile.set({
            id: userId, email: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email,
            creationTime: moment().format(),
            lastSignInTime: moment().format()
          });
        }
      }).toPromise();
```

***Versions:***

```
 "typescript": "2.4.2"
 "rxjs": "5.5.2",
```

Comment: Have you considered convert `Observable` into `Promise` which is only exectued one time?

Comment: You can also do `.take(1)` to force the subscription to complete after receiving one value.

Comment: I tried. But no difference. Please see the update @Szarik

Comment: @Sampath perhaps calling `.complete()` on `observer` could work?

Comment: `usubscribe()` the object after you take the data

Comment: @Sampath Have you imported `toPromise` from `rxjs` operators and I assume that you used `then` method on `uerProfiles$`?

Comment: @Sampath you used in the wrong way. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39022416/4700863)

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that? @PankajParkar

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have found a solution here using both mix of `Angularfire2` and `firebase native API`.

I got this solution from [**Michael here**](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-cloud-firestore-discuss/Ls1HZq8YfnM).

[**Firestore native API**](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query)

```
get
get() returns firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot

Executes the query and returns the results as a QuerySnapshot.

Returns
non-null firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot A promise that will be resolved with the results of the query.
```

*.ts*

```
 constructor() {
     this.db = firebase.firestore();
  }

   async loginWithGoogle(): Promise<string> {
        try {
          const response = await this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider());
          const result = await this.afAuth.auth.getRedirectResult();
          this.user = result.user;
          const userId: string = result.user.uid;
          const userProfile: AngularFirestoreDocument<UserProfile> = this.fireStore.doc(`userProfile/${userId}`);
          const res = await this.db.collection("userProfiles").where("email", "==", data).get();
          if (res.docs.length === 0) {
            await userProfile.set({
              id: userId,
              email: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email,
              creationTime: moment().format(),
              lastSignInTime: moment().format()
            });
          } else {
            await userProfile.update({
              lastSignInTime: moment().format()
            });
          }
          return result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email;
        }
        catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Promise way:

```
userProfiles$.toPromise().then((res) => {
   if (res.length == 0) {
      await userProfile.set({
         id: userId, email: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email,
         creationTime: moment().format(),
         lastSignInTime: moment().format()
      });
   }
}).catch(err => {
   // handle error
});
```

Firstly you convert it to promise then listen to it via `.then()` method and wait for resolved promise.

#### Observable .take(1)

```
userProfiles$.take(1).subscribe(async res => { //problem is here
        if (res.length == 0) {
          await userProfile.set({
            id: userId,
            email: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email,
            creationTime: moment().format(),
            lastSignInTime: moment().format()
          });
        } else {
          await userProfile.update({
            lastSignInTime: moment().format()
          });
        }
      });
```

Notice for `toPromise` way don't forget to import `toPromise` from rxjs operators and for `take` you should also import `take` method from rxjs

### Update. Angular version >= 6

Since angular 6 it is required to have rxjs >= 6. In which now operators like `take` are now importable and used in `.pipe()` method. [You can read more here](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/v6/migration#operator-pipe-syntax)

```
// somewhere at the top of file
import { take } from 'rxjs/operators';

userProfiles$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(async res => { //problem is here
        if (res.length == 0) {
          await userProfile.set({
            id: userId,
            email: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.email,
            creationTime: moment().format(),
            lastSignInTime: moment().format()
          });
        } else {
          await userProfile.update({
            lastSignInTime: moment().format()
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: This is not working `[ts] Property 'take' does not exist on type 'Observable<UserProfile[]>'.`. I have imported it like this `import { map, first, take } from 'rxjs/operators';`

Comment: What's your `typescript` and `rxjs` version?

Comment: Just curious try to use this `(userProfiles$ as any).take(1)...` and check if it works properly. It's not best solution, but im just curious about it.

Comment: Promise way is not working at all. No errors too. Just not fire that method.

Comment: Same here too `(userProfiles$ as any).take(1)`. Not fire that method.

Comment: Just for everybody looking at it now. Its `.pipe(take(1))`